# Fixed sidebar during scrolling in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I want my left sidebar to fix when the sidebars bottom content is being displayed, and stay fixed when scrolling until the footer. Then whenever you scroll back up the sidebar will stay fixed when the TOP of the sidebar gets to the top. 
Can I use Bootstrap affix for this? 
It is exactly like this (left sidebar behaviour) : http://www.spelbloggare.se/

I am very thankful for any help, I don´t know whether to paste all of my code here (it is so much) but I have a header, sidebar, content and a footer.

Comment: is it possible to post the css, only classes which you used for side nav .?

Answer (score 1):

See this:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  console.log( "document ready!" );

  var $sticky = $('.sticky');
  var $stickyrStopper = $('.sticky-stopper');
  if (!!$sticky.offset()) { // make sure ".sticky" element exists

    var generalSidebarHeight = $sticky.innerHeight();
    var stickyTop = $sticky.offset().top;
    var stickOffset = 0;
    var stickyStopperPosition = $stickyrStopper.offset().top;
    var stopPoint = stickyStopperPosition - generalSidebarHeight - stickOffset;
    var diff = stopPoint + stickOffset;

    $(window).scroll(function(){ // scroll event
      var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // returns number

      if (stopPoint < windowTop) {
          $sticky.css({ position: 'absolute', top: diff });
      } else if (stickyTop < windowTop+stickOffset) {
          $sticky.css({ position: 'fixed', top: stickOffset });
      } else {
          $sticky.css({position: 'absolute', top: 'initial'});
      }
    });

  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
}

.header {
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 90px;
}

.sidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.content {
  float: right;
  width: 640px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 800px;
}

.footer {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 820px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    This is header
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar sticky">
    This is side bar
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    This is main content
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="sticky-stopper"></div>
    This is my footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal example of how you could do it. You'll need jQuery for this example.

```js
$(function() {
  var sidebar = $('.sidebar');
  var top = sidebar.offset().top - parseFloat(sidebar.css('margin-top'));

  $(window).scroll(function(event) {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y >= top) {
      sidebar.addClass('fixed');
    } else {
      sidebar.removeClass('fixed');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* -- Needed things -- */
  /* top margin on sidebar */
  .sidebar,
  .content {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  /* fixed sidebar which will be added from JS */
  .fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }
  
/* -- Code below is only for example -- */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 20px;
}

p {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  border: green 2px solid;
}

.content {
  width: 70%;
  border: 2px solid green;
  float: right;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">Navigation</div>
<div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed mollis diam sed risus aliquet, in vestibulum neque lacinia. Ut nec consequat dolor. Aenean venenatis justo nec sagittis lacinia. Quisque metus tortor, porta quis nulla sit amet, dictum facilisis
    orci. Quisque ipsum dui, feugiat a lorem venenatis, interdum porttitor lacus. Sed ac augue vitae tellus fringilla tincidunt. In id ultrices erat. Vestibulum ut suscipit massa, ac pulvinar erat. Duis in accumsan eros. Ut elementum accumsan libero consectetur
    scelerisque. Mauris ut turpis id nibh iaculis egestas eget ornare risus. Donec justo tellus, rutrum et euismod eleifend, eleifend vel augue. Quisque vulputate mi ut ante aliquet, ut molestie orci rutrum. Donec molestie, mauris vitae accumsan venenatis,
    felis turpis tempor erat, sit amet euismod est dui vel libero. Nunc sed turpis nec ipsum tristique porta. Ut viverra sollicitudin velit. Fusce ac ante ac nunc posuere tempus. Aenean aliquet lacus arcu, id tristique lacus tempor at. In vel enim dolor.
    Sed sed sem quam. Pellentesque scelerisque malesuada quam in tempus. Pellentesque commodo vestibulum varius. Suspendisse in sollicitudin magna. Aenean condimentum, quam non rhoncus hendrerit, augue augue cursus nulla, ut commodo dolor justo in orci.
    Vivamus auctor vitae dolor at porttitor. Praesent euismod pellentesque sollicitudin. Phasellus blandit adipiscing dictum. Etiam hendrerit scelerisque quam nec suscipit. Mauris elit orci, facilisis ut fermentum ac, consequat vel nisl. Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed mollis diam sed risus aliquet, in vestibulum neque lacinia. Ut nec consequat dolor. Aenean venenatis justo nec sagittis lacinia. Quisque metus tortor, porta quis nulla sit amet, dictum facilisis orci. Quisque
    ipsum dui, feugiat a lorem venenatis, interdum porttitor lacus. Sed ac augue vitae tellus fringilla tincidunt. In id ultrices erat. Vestibulum ut suscipit massa, ac pulvinar erat. Duis in accumsan eros. Ut elementum accumsan libero consectetur scelerisque.
    Mauris ut turpis id nibh iaculis egestas eget ornare risus. Donec justo tellus, rutrum et euismod eleifend, eleifend vel augue. Quisque vulputate mi ut ante aliquet, ut molestie orci rutrum. Donec molestie, mauris vitae accumsan venenatis, felis turpis
    tempor erat, sit amet euismod est dui vel libero. Nunc sed turpis nec ipsum tristique porta. Ut viverra sollicitudin velit. Fusce ac ante ac nunc posuere tempus. Aenean aliquet lacus arcu, id tristique lacus tempor at. In vel enim dolor. Sed sed sem
    quam. Pellentesque scelerisque malesuada quam in tempus. Pellentesque commodo vestibulum varius. Suspendisse in sollicitudin magna. Aenean condimentum, quam non rhoncus hendrerit, augue augue cursus nulla, ut commodo dolor justo in orci. Vivamus auctor
    vitae dolor at porttitor. Praesent euismod pellentesque sollicitudin. Phasellus blandit adipiscing dictum. Etiam hendrerit scelerisque quam nec suscipit. Mauris elit orci, facilisis ut fermentum ac, consequat vel nisl. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed mollis diam sed risus aliquet, in vestibulum neque lacinia. Ut nec consequat dolor. Aenean venenatis justo nec sagittis lacinia. Quisque metus tortor, porta quis nulla sit amet, dictum facilisis orci. Quisque ipsum
    dui, feugiat a lorem venenatis, interdum porttitor lacus. Sed ac augue vitae tellus fringilla tincidunt. In id ultrices erat. Vestibulum ut suscipit massa, ac pulvinar erat. Duis in accumsan eros. Ut elementum accumsan libero consectetur scelerisque.
    Mauris ut turpis id nibh iaculis egestas eget ornare risus. Donec justo tellus, rutrum et euismod eleifend, eleifend vel augue. Quisque vulputate mi ut ante aliquet, ut molestie orci rutrum. Donec molestie, mauris vitae accumsan venenatis, felis turpis
    tempor erat, sit amet euismod est dui vel libero. Nunc sed turpis nec ipsum tristique porta. Ut viverra sollicitudin velit. Fusce ac ante ac nunc posuere tempus. Aenean aliquet lacus arcu, id tristique lacus tempor at. In vel enim dolor. Sed sed sem
    quam. Pellentesque scelerisque malesuada quam in tempus. Pellentesque commodo vestibulum varius. Suspendisse in sollicitudin magna. Aenean condimentum, quam non rhoncus hendrerit, augue augue cursus nulla, ut commodo dolor justo in orci. Vivamus auctor
    vitae dolor at porttitor. Praesent euismod pellentesque sollicitudin. Phasellus blandit adipiscing dictum. Etiam hendrerit scelerisque quam nec suscipit. Mauris elit orci, facilisis ut fermentum ac, consequat vel nisl.

  </p>
</div>
```